# use swapi with javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use the SWAPI and I'm trying to get the climate of the planet, but I get "undefined"

Basically what I want to have the climate to be "arid" not "undefined".

Maybe **"xhttp.response.climate"** is not the correct way to do it. But how ?

This is my code:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
   console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
   document.write('The climate of the planet is: ' + 
   '<strong>' + xhttp.response.climate + '</strong>');
 }
}

 xhttp.open("GET", "http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/", true);

 xhttp.send();
```

I the BROWSER I get this:

```
The climate of the planet is: undefined
```

and this is what I see in the DEVTOOLS:

```
Object {name: "Tatooine", rotation_period: "23", orbital_period: "304", 
diameter: "10465", climate: "arid"…}
climate:"arid"
created:"2014-12-09T13:50:49.641000Z"
diameter:"10465"
edited:"2014-12-21T20:48:04.175778Z"
films: Array(5)
gravity:"1 standard"
name: "Tatooine"
orbital_period:"304"
population: "200000"
residents: Array(10)
rotation_period: "23"
surface_water: "1" 
terrain: "desert"
url: "http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line, you parse the string into an object:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
```

This creates a new object from the string, but it does not reassign the values of `xhttp.response`.

That means that `xhttp.response.climate` will not work, because `xhttp.response` is still a string, so this will not work:

```
document.write('The climate of the planet is: ' + 
'<strong>' + xhttp.response.climate + '</strong>');
```

Try this instead:

```
var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
console.log(data);
document.write('The climate of the planet is: ' + 
'<strong>' + data.climate + '</strong>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The response contains the object as JSON string. You correctly log this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
```

To fix the document.write part, you'd change it into:

```
document.write('The climate of the planet is: <strong>' + JSON.parse(xhttp.response).climate + '</strong>');
```

Or better yet, catch it into a var for easy reference:

```
var planet = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
console.log(planet.climate);
```